# How do I prevent Chrome in Android from downmixing my audio tag to mono when using the mic?

Tags: android, reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm trying to mix the microphone and html5 audio together in a web app. On Android, in Chrome, when I combine the signals the music gets forced into mono. I'm hoping it's a simple misunderstanding of how splitters and mergers work in Web Audio. I have my ugly code below, would love to know if there's a better way

This is working in Chrome on a MacBook Pro, but on the Android tablet it's a total fail. I've tried NOT accessing the mic at all on the tablet and when I do that the music remains in stereo. But once I add the mic to the mixer everything gets summed to mono...

```
export async function AudioConnect() {
  //get sources
  audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
  mic = await getMicrophone();
  audioContext = getAudioContext();
  //set up nodes
  audioElementNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
  micNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mic);
  gainLeft = new GainNode(audioContext, { gain: 0.5 });
  gainRight = new GainNode(audioContext, { gain: 0.5 });
  //set up analyser and channels
  analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
  analyser.fftSize = 64;
  freqDomain = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(2);
  mixer = audioContext.createChannelMerger(4);
  //connect nodes
  audioElementNode.connect(splitter);
  micNode.connect(analyser);
  micNode.connect(gainLeft);
  micNode.connect(gainRight);
  gainLeft.connect(mixer, 0, 0);
  gainRight.connect(mixer, 0, 1);
  splitter.connect(mixer, 0, 2);
  splitter.connect(mixer, 1, 3);
  //output
  mixer.connect(audioContext.destination);
}
```

What should happen is the microphone should go to both the left and right channels and the music should remain in stereo. But as mentioned, the music gets mixed down to mono once the mic is engaged.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The four channels from the mixer get mixed when playing out to the audio context.  What is the value of `audioContext.destination.channelCount`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sorry I'm so late... anyway it's logging as 2 channels...

Comment: I don't have an answer on why this is not working. I think it should. Perhaps the best approach now is to file a [bug](https://crbug.com/new) so people familiar with mic input and webaudio can investigate.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? There are similar situations when iOS used microphone, that the audiocontext turns to mono. I think they call it switching to "call" mode. Very annoying to see that it also happens in Android as well.